What type of visa should I get to attend an event in France for more than 90 days?
I want to attend an upcoming event (link), and it is more than 90 days. I need a visa, but I do not know if I should ask for a long-stay  visa. This is my first visa request.
I appreciate any help you can provide.
Edit 1:  I am one of Laureat, I will receive full accommodation and all my travel tickets will be covered by the international organization (CIMPA[cimpa.info]) cimpa.info/en/node/7404

If you're willing to skip a week or so at the beginning or end, or leave the Schengen area for a few days in the middle, you could avoid the whole issue...

IHP likely has an office for international visitors; you could contact them to ask for advice.  You might need their assistance anyway if you need to apply for a longer-term visa.

Do you have prior travel history? Getting a Schengen visa without one could be difficult.

It appears that this specific event is not a continuous 90+ day stretch but rather four one-week sessions spread over four months. Is it possible to travel four times for a duration of one week each time? Edit: rereading the page, it seems that maybe there are workshops and then something separate that spans the entire period?


@NateEldredge I am from Morocco,
Traveller no I don't have
shoover that's what I guessed,

thanks guys for the replies and the help

You may look into a Student visa but I’m not sure this course meets the criteria for this (due to the absence of any selection criteria or process).

Your current situation will probably be important as well. Your profile says you are a PhD student, is that still the case? Where? Morocco? Are PhD candidates treated as university employees where you are or not? Honestly, the whole thing doesn't seem set up to accommodate junior researchers from middle income countries and getting any kind of visa for this might be very difficult.

If you want to stay in France for the whole period and are not an EU / EEA / Swiss citizen, you definitely need a long-stay visa. That's trivial: There are in fact multiple visas or permits with very different requirements that could be relevant but any stay longer than 90 days is, by definition, a “long stay” and that's the cutoff defining the scope of Schengen regulations.
The question therefore becomes which French visa might cover this trip. Your plan does not seem to fit any of the usual categories very well. I doubt obtaining a student visa would be possible as you won't get an acceptance letter or campus France number for such a free, part-time event. What's left is probably the generic “visiteur” visa, even though it is primarily intended for tourism, not training. You can find more information on the different types of visas and the documents required on service-public.fr and france-visas,
Alternatively, you could also consider travelling back and forth as needed. As long as the total duration of stay doesn't exceed 90 days, you could theoretically do that on a short-stay (Schengen) visa.
In both cases, you will need to establish that all this is really worth the trouble and that you have enough money to either reside in Corsica and Paris for 3+ months or pay for all the travel and hotel stays. Either of these will be quite expensive and if this trip appears to be beyond your financial means, it could reinforce the suspicion that you are looking for a pretext to get a visa instead of being genuinely interested in this course. Anything you can provide to establish that you are working as a researcher in this specific field could therefore be useful. Financial support from your current university would probably be a good thing too.

Thanks for that,
I am one of Laureat, I will receive full accommodation and all my travel tickets will be covered by the international organization (CIMPA[cimpa.info])  https://www.cimpa.info/en/node/7404

As it looks like it's one week a month for 4 months, it probably makes more sense to apply for a short-stay visa for those four trips.

(+1) Worth noting that the info in the CIMPA link states A candidate will commit to spend at least 2/3 of the time of the programme in Paris to be admissible. @DonFreecs you should edit your question to include the info in your comment in your question (which would have been helpful at the start).

@Relaxed visiting france-visas website mention that  You are replying to invitations and requests from your partners in France. You want to attend or participate in trade fairs, seminars or conferences related to your professional activity.
source: https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/business-travel
so I think the visa I should request is short-visa for business purpose.

@DonFreecs Yes this could be a good fit but this works best for a short-stay visa and if you are an employee of your university, that's why I asked for details in a comment. The sponsorship you mentioned should be helpful in any case, maybe CIMPA can provide some advice regarding the visa application?
